# Is there any way to display data based on className when onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have some data along with icons.
for suppose I am using two icons and two buttons one is info and another is the user. This is an example but I have a few more extra icons with buttons. If I click the user button I need to display only the user icon and the relevant data. I don't want to write each data conditionally because the data is a little bit more.

[Please give a look for better understanding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bulma-font-awesome-hn4jmc)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use a piece of state to manage what to display. Not so much `className`. You want your markup to *react* to the state changes.

Your button clicks would set the new state and your component would display content specific to that state:

```
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      display: ""
    };
```

Then set state based on button clicks:

```
        <button
          onClick={() => this.setState({ ...this.state, display: "info" })}
        >
```

Then conditionally output data:

```
        {this.state.display === 'info' && <div><i className="fa fa-info" /> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
        printing and typesetting industry.
        <br /></div>}
```

Note, the use of `&&`. It is common practice to use the logical short circuit to display data conditionally...

Comment: I have more data displaying randomly, based on your logic I keep the condition for every data, but it is complex. Is there any other way?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by more data or where is coming from. But generally, if something matches a pattern you would map over the data and output that way. If you give more context....

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally display certain data according to your data schema:-

given if you've data like shown below:-

```js
const examples = [
  {
    id: "1a",
    type: "info",
    desc: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`
  },
  {
    id: "2a",
    type: "user",
    desc: `Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.`
  },
  {
    id: "3a",
    type: "user",
    desc: `Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.`
  },
  {
    id: "4a",
    type: "user",
    desc: `Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.`
  },
  {
    id: "5a",
    type: "info",
    desc: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`
  }
];
```

And you could conditionally display them according to your needs:-

- display **icon** depending on `data.type`
- display **filtered** `data` on `onClick` event

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      filtered: examples
    };
  }

  info() {
    alert("display only info icons with the data");
    this.setState({
      ...this.state, 
      filtered: examples.filter(data => data.type === "info")
    });
  }

  user() {
    alert("display only user icons with the data");
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      filtered: examples.filter(data => data.type === "user")
    });
  }

  reset() {
    alert("display all icons with the data");
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      filtered: examples
    });
  }

  dataTypes(type) {
    if (type === "user") return "fa fa-user";
    if (type === "info") return "fa fa-info";
    // add more
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.info()}>Info</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.user()}>User</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.reset()}>Reset</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.state.filtered.map(data => (
          <div key={data.id}>
            <i className={this.dataTypes(data.type)} /> {data.desc}
            <br />
            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can refer to this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bulma-font-awesome-7jjd8k) for live references.